# Error while producing an ARMA model using the TSA package in R

Tags: r, time-series

Had anyone else had this problem, or even better, does anyone know why this is giving me an error?

I'm attempting to create an ARMA model of order 3, 3.  I'm using the TSA package.

```
stocks_arma <- arma(stocks$close, order = c(3,3))
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
Warning message:
In arma(VIXts, order = c(3, 3)) : Hessian negative-semidefinite
```

I understand that a Hessian negative-semidefinite matrix is a bad thing because we usually want global mins/maxes.  However, I don't understand why this is happening.  I am unsure is this is a mathematical issue or a syntactial issue.

My data is a very modest vector of 1000 entries.  Here is one-tenth of it:

```
  15.14 15.31 15.08 15.24 16.41 17.99 17.92 16.65 16.68 18.61 18.49 19.08 17.58 18.42 17.59 16.69 18.60 17.81 18.12 18.33 18.83 16.62 16.97 15.03 15.07 15.22 15.27 16.14 15.59 16.29 16.37 15.11 14.33 14.55 15.43 15.71 16.32 15.73 14.84 16.81 15.43 14.15 13.98 14.07 13.88 14.18 14.59 14.51 14.05 15.80 16.41 16.28 14.38 15.63 17.74 17.98 17.47 17.83 17.06 16.49 16.35 15.18 15.96 15.11 15.02 14.02 13.45 14.29 14.63 14.85 13.70 14.74 15.28 15.32 15.99 15.95 15.64 17.57 18.96 18.93 18.03 16.70 17.53 19.34 20.47 18.62 16.27 15.45 16.16 16.48 17.11 16.74 18.36 17.95 18.72 18.05 17.10 17.50 16.66 16.80 17.08 19.71 19.45 19.72 20.38
```

There is nothing overtly fishy about the values at all.

Any insight is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @gung for the comment.  I suppose that upon reflection this is a more technical question about a specific library of functions used in R. How can I go about migrating my question to that area?

Comment: @Stat I don't have the reputation necessary to create a new tag.  However I will flag for migration.

Comment: does the problem happen with the subset of data you posted?

Comment: I'm not sure that this shouldn't be treated as a stats problem rather than a programming one, or at least as something at the interface of the two.